# ArcGIS Pro Feature Class Iterator wildcard with or without enterprise GDB fully qualified feature class names?

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-class, iterator

I'm using the Feature Class iterator in an ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder model to iterate over all feature classes with a name that start with (eg) "blah".

I can make this work for our enterprise geodatabase using the wildcard:  `*.blah*`

I can make this work for file geodatabases using the wildcard:  `blah*`

Of course, the "*." is required for enterprise geodatabases (at least with MS SQL), because the feature classes are fully qualified with the database name and schema/owner name.

However, I cannot find a way to make this work reliably for both situations using the same iterator wildcard.  If use the wildcard, `*blah*`, it not only finds all feature classes that start with "blah", but of course it also finds some feature classes with "blah" elsewhere in their names (which I do NOT want).

Is there any way to iterate over feature classes where the name starts with a particular string that works for both file geodatabases AND for enterprise geodatabases?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could use an Calculate Value tool to check the workspace name.

[image: Model]

The expression I am using here simply checks for ".sde" in the path:

[image: Expression]

Expression: `checkName(r"%Workspace%")`

Code Block:

```
def checkName(w):
   import os
   n = os.path.basename(w)
   if ".sde" in n:
      return "*.blah*"
   else:
      return "blah*"
```

If the Workspace is an enterprise geodatabase, then the wildcard value is set with the *.blah* value.  Likewise, if it's not, it uses the blah* value.

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion.  I guess, similarly, you could use something like `if '.' in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()[0]`.

Comment: The only thing is you'd have to set a workspace in the snippet in order to list feature classes.  However, checking for a '.' in the n variable would also work.